# Priority queue with Worker Pod AutoScaler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I have a simple AWS SQS FIFO queue implemented with worker pod autoscaler [WPA](https://github.com/practo/k8s-worker-pod-autoscaler), now i want to make that queue a priority queue, one option would be using amazon MQ but its costly and its purpose is actually different, another option would be to create multiple N queues where N is the priority of the queue, now the actual problem is how will the worker Pod Autoscaler work, how will it select the queue and how will it autoscale.